# AngularJS: Trying to add insert_id to model

Tags: angularjs

I am inserting a record (works great) and the network tab of Chrome Tools is showing this as the response:

```
{"message":25}
```

That too is correct since the API is programmed to return the insert_id.

However, on the success of the promise, I am trying to add that id to the farmer object but it is not working.

Here is that method:

```
$scope.insertFarmer = function() {
  if($scope.farmer.id){
      alert("We have a farmer");
  } else {
      $scope.farmers.push($scope.farmer);
      var data = $http.post('/api/farmers', $scope.farmer);
      $scope.farmer.id = data.message;
  } // end if
  return true;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http.post('/api/farmers', $scope.farmer);` return only with a HttpPromise. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

You should do something like this:

```
  $http.post('/api/farmers', $scope.farmer).
  success(function(data,status){
    $scope.farmer.id = data.message;
  }).
  error(function(data, status){
    $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
    $scope.status = status;
  });
```

See the example on the bottom of the link.